# find the first value multiple times in a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, data.table

I am trying to find specific values, in this case the first ones, multiple times in a time series. The data looks like this

```
data <- data.table::data.table(value = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                               time  = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21))
```

Now I want to find the first values where `value == 1` and give me the time to this.
The result should look like this for time: 4, 14, 18

It would also be a great help if the solution would be flexible so you can skip small numbers of following zeros.
For this case the result would look like this for time: 4, 18 because you can skip the 2 zeros in the middle.

I already tried solution with `which(min)` but it only gives me the first value and not the following first values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` `rleid` -

```
data$time[!duplicated(data.table::rleid(data$value)) & data$value == 1]
#[1]  4 14 18
```

If you want to skip some count of consecutive zero you may use this function.

```
skip_zero <- function(df, n = 0) {
  inds <- data.table::rleid(df$value)
  df$value[ave(inds, inds, FUN = length)  <= n & df$value == 0] <- 1
  inds <- data.table::rleid(df$value)
  df$time[!duplicated(inds) & df$value == 1]
}

skip_zero(data)
#[1]  4 14 18

skip_zero(data, 2)
#[1]  4 14
```

Comment: I tried your solution because I like it the data.table way. What do I have to change if there are not only zeros I want to ignore but also 3, 4, 5 etc... and the value I am looking for is not 1 and instead 4?

Comment: Change in the second line from `df$value == 0` to `df$value %in% c(0, 3, 4, 5)` and in the last line `df$value == 1` to `df$valie == 4`.

Comment: thank you very much, great solution! I made a mistake with my real data so it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a group for each consecutive run of 0&1s. Then you can group by this and take the first row in each.

```
data %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(value  != lag(value , 1, TRUE))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(row_number()==1, value == 1) %>%
  select(-group)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with(
  rle(data$value),
  c(1, 1 + cumsum(lengths))[which(values == 1)]
)
# [1]  4 14 18
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69390362/find-the-first-value-multiple-times-in-a-time-series-in-r#comment122648860_69391336) that he/she *like it the data.table way*.

So, here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach which finds occurrences of *subsequences* in the  `value` column using `shift()` and *join*:

```
library(data.table)
data[, shift(value, 1:0)][.(0, 1), on = .(V1, V2), which = TRUE]
```

> ```
> [1]  4 14 18
> ```

Here, we look for occurrences of the subsequence `(0, 1)` in `value`. This can be easily extended to cover arbitrary subsequences, e.g.,

```
data[, shift(value, 3:0)][.(0, 0, 0, 1), on = .(V1, V2, V3, V4), which = TRUE]
```

> ```
> [1]  4 14
> ```

which skips occurrences of two subsequent zeros.

#### Explanation

TO BE COMPLETED

#### Extension

Generic function TO BE COMPLETED